# Unable to see system navigation gesture setting

Tags: settings, tablet, 9.0-pie, navigation-bar, gestures

It appears that I don't have all the setting for gestures on my Android tablet.

So that's how it looks on my tablet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhKMc.jpg

That's how it should look like I believe: https://icdn3.digitaltrends.com/image/digitaltrends/android-10-gestures-how-to-turn-on-2-1080x2160.jpg

When I was setting device up it proposed to choose between 3 button navigation and gesture navigation.

The tablet is Lenovo Yoga Smart Tab.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gesture navigation is [available starting in Android 10](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-10-gestures-1025113/) (API version 29).

Your phone is setup with gesture navigation because it is running Android 10+, but your tablet might be running Android 9 (based on your question tags).

Check to see if there's a system update for your tablet, otherwise you'll either have to;

1. Wait until Android 10 becomes available for your Lenovo Yoga Smart Tab.
2. Find an alternative launcher app you can install that contains gesture navigation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a bit confused, because when I was setting up tablet for the first time it proposed me to choose between gesture and button navigation. Eventually I found it was Lenovo tablet specific setting which I found in Settings->Display->Navigation Bar (So it has Lenovo specific launcher I suppose)

Comment: Glad you figured it out - and also interesting to hear Lenovo has provided their own gesture navigation pre-Android 10.  :)